# Unsure of clojure type

Tags: clojure

Can anybody explain what the type below is in the code below which I seen in the clojure docs for string/replace?

```
(clojure.string/replace "The color is red" #"red" "blue")
```

I am talking specifically about the `#"red" "blue"`

Also, if I have an array-map like this:

```
{"red" "blue"}
```

How could I transform this array-map into this unknown type?

```
{"red" "blue"} ;=> #"red" "blue"???
```

Comment: Note that {"red" "blue"} does not commit to being anything more than a persistent map - Clojure may construct it either as an array-map or a hash-map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a map {"red" "blue"} and you'd like to use that to drive the replacement, you could do:

```
;; Generic form of your question - uses re-pattern to create a regex
(defn replace-with [s find replacement]
  (clojure.string/replace s (re-pattern find) replacement))

;; Walk through every [find replace] pair in replacements map 
;; and repeatedly apply it to string
(defn replace-with-all [s replacements]
  (reduce (fn [s [f r]] (replace-with s f r)) 
          s
          replacements))

(replace-with-all "foo bar baz" {"foo" "blue" "baz" "red"})
;; "blue bar red"
```

Comment: Could you explain this argument list please fn [s [f r]]

Comment: Sure, there are two arguments: s (string) and an unnamed 2-element vector which will be bound to each key-value pair in the map. I use destructuring to bind the key to f and the value to r. See http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring) to learn more about destructuring.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, this has opened up a whole new bit of learning

Answer (score 3):

In Clojure, **#"....."** is a Regular Expression definition. So you are replacing `red` with `blue`.

> (replace s match replacement)
> Replaces all instance of match with replacement in s.
>
> match/replacement can be:
>
> string / string
> char / char
> pattern / (string or function of match).

But I didn't understand what do you mean by 'transform this array-map into this unknown type'.

Comment: Given your explanation, how could I turn an array map like {"red" "blue"} into 2 regex expressions for the key and the value of the array-map.